# How can I give Negative value to Height or Width of a View in React Naitve?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a selector in react native using PANRESPONDER in reactNative. Actually width of a View is oriented from left to right, and Height of the View is oriented from top to bottom. I want to dynamically reverse the box.
So I am giving width and height as a negative Value. But the View disappears. How could I reverse the View ?

Comment: I suggest you edit the question with a bit more information. It's not clear what your are trying to achieve, so it's difficult to help.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203154/get-size-of-a-view-in-react-native

Answer (score 1):

If anybody ends up here looking for how to make a value negative of say the screen dimensions so you can move an element around in say a slider..

```
let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
let screenWidthNegative = parseInt('-' + screenWidth);

<View style={[styles.thisViewsStyle, {marginLeft: screenWidthNegative}]}></View>
```

Comment: `let screenWidthNegative = -screenWidth;` works more easily