# React Native Image doesn't resize on device (iOS) orientation change?

Tags: react-native

I'm a React Native n00b, so perhaps I'm missing something brutally obvious.

```
      <Image
        source={signoutGradient}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={{ height: 60, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' }}
      >
        <Button
          title="SIGN OUT"
          color="#FFFFFF"
          onPress={this.onPressSignOut}
        />
      </Image>
```

... gives me this in portrait on my iOS device (good):

[image: portrait]

... but this in landscape mode (bad) when I rotate the device. How come? How to fix this? I am expecting that the size of the actual PNG image file doesn't matter, because it should get stretched to be larger if it needs to be. That doesn't seem to be happening.

[image: landscape]

Comment: Try `resizeMode="contain"` and maybe you will have to set its width and height to be fixed with respect to your window dimensions

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf how do i "set its width and height to be fixed with respect to your window dimensions" ?

Comment: From [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32031698/5890227), you can get the height and width of your window. Then you would set your image to be for example `height/10` and `width/2`, etc. Let me know how it goes and I will help more.

Answer (score 1):

FYI the `Dimensions` module doesn't automatically update when the screen rotates. It is only an option if you can somehow detect the rotation and force a rerender.

One option is wrapping the components that need to be responsive with a `View` and then use the `onLayout` property. The function passed as `onLayout` will receive a `{nativeEvent: { layout: {x, y, width, height}}}` containing the `View`'s updated position and dimensions any time they change; if you write these to the component's state you can automatically recalculate your new height and width and trigger a rerender when the screen rotates (e.g. set `onLayout` on your root `View` and update the image's `width` to be the width of the entire screen). You can `ctrl+f` for "onLayout" [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html).

The `flex` style prop also updates on rotation, so you could possibly set `flex:1` for example on your root component and somehow use flexbox to keep everything styled responsively.

Comment: As much as possible already has `flex: 1`. The issue is that the size of the component does change but `resizeMode="cover"` does not rescale the image as it should upon rotation

Comment: @xaphod What happens if you update state for the component containing the image after a rotation? Does it resize?

Answer (score 0):

Yep adding flex: 1 to your image style should fix your issue. As long as you are setting only a default height and not a width. In my case I had set both width and height for my image and had the same issue when the device went landscape. Once I removed the width and added flex: 1 my issue was resolved

Comment: No, flex: 1 causes the image to take up a lot more space than it should, ie ignore its fixed height. Wrapping it in a View fixes that but the image still does not scale as resizeMode="cover" implies it should.