# Image doesn't align on top of its container React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to align image on top of its container in react native, especially on landscape.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor: 'green'}} >
      <Image resizeMode='contain'style={{ flex:1,width:"100%",height:"100%"}} source={{uri:"https://www.tageblatt.lu/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/250112_cx__cy__cw__ch_-1-739x493.jpeg"}}   />
    </View>
    <View style={{width:"15%",backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
      <Text style={{color:"white",padding:7}}>{caption}</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

The output of this code is :

[image]

And on landscape:

[image]

The desired output is:

[image]

Which I get on landscape orientation if I press control+s (saving) on my editor.
[I follow this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380120/react-native-image-doesnt-resize-on-device-ios-orientation-change), but with no solution for me .
I tried different values for resizeMode also .

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the `resizeMode` ?

```
<Image resizeMode='cover' ... />
```

Comment: yes but the image is spread in the container, https://ibb.co/7QjJFBZ