# ReactNative get the absolute position of a view relative to the screen

Tags: react-native

with react native.

I can get the position and size with `onLayout`, but I want to get the absolute position of a view relative to the screen

please! the absolute position of a view relative to the screen

not the absolute position of a view relative to the parent view

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get size of a View in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203154/get-size-of-a-view-in-react-native)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you can use [measure(callback)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#measure-callback) it Determines the location on screen, width, and height of the given view and returns the values via an async callback.

a better example can be found here [React Native: Getting the position of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751446/7149898)

```
<View
  ref={(ref) => { this.marker = ref }}
  onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => {
    if (this.marker) {
      this.marker.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
                console.log(x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY);
       })
    }
  }}
 >
```

Comment: Gives me only `undefined`, with and without setTimeout, as parameters :/

Comment: please check now I updated the answer this was because the old ref string not supported any more

Comment: On iOs pageX is sometime equal to the width of the view. Any idea why?

Comment: @Zach it is normal when on the edge of the screen

Comment: You should `collapsible={false}` into View to prevent Android native view collapsing for optimization.

Answer (score -3):

You might want to use the "onTouchStart". it Determines the location on screen from pageX, pageY of the given view and returns the values.

```
<View
  onTouchStart={(e) => {console.log('touchMove', e.nativeEvent.pageY)}}
 >
```

a better example can be found here: 
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html