# How to position a View at the bottom of a ScrollView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I would like to create a screen with a ScrollView with some input fields in it, and a Button (actually 2 buttons in a normal View) at the bottom of the screen. This should be pretty easy, BUT, ***I want to position my button at the very bottom of the screen*** even if there isn't enough element in the ScrollView to fill the whole screen. I could use absolute positioning, BUT my ScrollView can be bigger (higher) then my screen, and in this case, the button should be at the end of the ScrollView. (So it would be out of the screen, which means the user should scoll down to see the button).

I've tried a lot of things, but the Button always comes right after the other elements inside the ScollView.

In the picture the scrollview has a blue border, and the normal view which contains the buttons has black border.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code so we can have a better idea about how the view is rendered?

Comment: I have a workaround now, but thank you for your interest. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Found the best solution.

The key is the **contentContainerStyle** property (doc: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle). "These styles will be applied to the scroll view content container which wraps all of the child views. "

After setting *flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'column'* in contentContainerStyle, one can set *justifyContent: 'flex-start'* for the upper container view with the text, and *justifyContent: 'flex-end'* for the lower container view with the buttons.

```html
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'column' }}
  style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', paddingBottom: 20 }}
>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}>
    <Text>Some text with different length in different cases, or some input fileds.</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[commonStyles.greenButton, styles.buttonPadding]}>
        <Text style={commonStyles.greenButtonTitle}>Next</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cancelButtonContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.cancelButton}>Cancel</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
</ScrollView>;
```

Comment: Works very well and is compatible with `KeyboardAvoidingView`.

Comment: Nice, works fine. Thanks for sharing. `flex-direction: column` is default in react and not needed.

Answer (score 8):

```
<ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      }}>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this.

The main idea is to **set the height of the View** with the texts and input fields **to match exactly the height of the screen minus the View which contains the buttons**.

The challenge is to calculate this height. Abhishek Kumar's answer helped me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41398953/4109477) See my code below:

```
         import { View, ScrollView, Text, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

         const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

          class MyClass extends React.Component {

          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {buttonViewHeight: 0};
          }

          find_dimesions(layout){
            this.setState({buttonViewHeight: layout.height});
          }
          render() {
            return (
              <View style={{minHeight: screenHeight, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <ScrollView style={{minHeight: screenHeight}}>
                 <View style={{minHeight: screenHeight}}>
                    <View style={{minHeight: screenHeight - this.state.buttonViewHeight, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'red', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1}]}>
                      <Text>Some text with different length in different cases, or some input fileds.</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View onLayout={(event) => { this.find_dimesions(event.nativeEvent.layout) }} style={{paddingBottom: 50, flex: 1, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'green'}}>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        style={[commonStyles.greenButton, styles.buttonPadding]} >
                        <Text style={commonStyles.greenButtonTitle}>Next</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.cancelButtonContainer} >
                        <Text style={styles.cancelButton}>Cancel</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </ScrollView>
              </View>
          }
   }
```

On the picture below you can see the result

[image: This is how it looks now]

*This solution will cause an animation like effect as the view renders multiple times, because of the changing of the View's height. The button's View "fade in" as you open the screen.*

If you find a better solution please let me know!