# How to make ScrollView only scroll when child size is larger in React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

How are you.

I would like to make component that has fixed height.

it's wrapped by ScrollView and I want this scrollview don't scroll if child height is small than fixed height.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Uhm, what about getting the child component height, comparing it to the parent fixed height and setting a boolean in your state which controls your ScrollView by its `scrollEnabled` prop?

Comment: I considered it, but I can't setState in render function, and I can only get child height in render function.

Comment: I don't think so. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30206471/7581249)

Comment: You are probably looking for the prop `scrollToOverflowEnabled` of `ScrollView` - this will enable the scroll only if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could render a normal View or a ScrollView based on some condition, consider this example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      childHeight: 0,
      screenHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height
    }
  }
  render(){
    const wrapper = this.state.childHeight > this.state.screenHeight ? ScrollView : View 
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        //onLayout passes a an object with a synthetic event that has a nativeEvent prop
        //I pull off the nativeEvent prop using deconstruction so I can get the height
        <View onLayout={
          ({ nativeEvent }) => {
            this.setState({ childHeight: nativeEvent.layout.height })
          }}>
        {children}
        </View>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

This is just one implementation, you could do it however you like. Here's some more info on the [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#onlayout) prop.

If you can't or don't want to use a View then you would have to do some other sort of layout calculation. One way is by manipulating your styles and the children prop:

```
const myStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  childStyle: {
    height: 180 
  }
})

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      childHeight: React.Children.count(props.children) * 180, 
      //get the count of how many children have been passed to your component
      //and multiple it by whatever height your children have set in their styles
      screenHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height 
  }
  render(){
    const wrapper = this.state.childHeight > this.state.screenHeight ? ScrollView : View
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        {children}
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

If the number of children can change throughout multiple renders then I would suggest learning about the [FlatList component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, this is implemented with `alwaysBounceVertical={false}`
https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#alwaysbouncevertical-ios.