# how to get height of react-native component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how to get the height of react component? I want to use the height value of a component as padding's value of other component, how to do it in react native? for example, I made a picker component from

```
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
```

I want to make a `<view>` component with padding value `padding:{Picker}.height`, how to do it?

**update**

thanks to @Aseem Gautam and @Aniket Kolekar, I have tried the solution for Picker Component but its not working, it worked nicely when I try it with View Component. why that could happen? does it mean the Picker Component not inherits View props? here the code that I have tried

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, SectionList } from "react-native";
import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";

export default class App extends Component {
  find_dimension(layout){
    const {x, y, width, height} = layout;
    console.warn(x);
    console.warn(y);
    console.warn(width);
    console.warn(height);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Picker onLayout={(event) => {this.find_dimension(event.nativeEvent.layout)}}>
          <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
          <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get size of a View in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203154/get-size-of-a-view-in-react-native)

Answer (score 6):

The `Picker` inherits `View` props. You can use the [onLayout](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout) event to get the `height`, `width`, `x` & `y` of the picker.

```
<Picker
  onLayout={(event) => {
  var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get height of a `View` in `React-Native`:

```html
<View onLayout={(event) => {
  let {height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
}} />
```

This should work for the `Picker` as well (if it is supported).